# Doit-on utiliser « emprise » ou « empire » dans « sous l'... de la colère » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions, usage

Les deux mots *emprise* et *empire* se ressemblent, et sont synonymes lorsqu'il s'agit d'être sous l'influence de quelques choses.

Je souhaite exprimer l'idée *être en colère*, j'obtiens deux solutions correctes *« sous l'empire de la colère »* et *« sous l'emprise de la colère »*.

Selon les usages de la langue française, lequel des deux dois-je utiliser pour ne pas surprendre l’interlocuteur ?

Comment: As a native French speaker, I never heard the expression "être sous l'empire de quelque chose"... So my answer is, use the second one. "Être sous l'emprise de quelque chose".

Comment: Je l'ai lu sur quelques arrêts de la Cour de Cassation : http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichJuriJudi.do?idTexte=JURITEXT000007091541

Comment: @Kii: Les deux se disent. Voir ma note à cl-r.

Comment: La forme idiomatique est "sous l'empire de la colère". Toutefois, l'expression "sous l'emprise de la colère", qui utilise les mots "emprise" et "colère" dans leur sens usuel est compréhensible et parfaitement acceptable sur un plan littéraire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le *[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/empire)* confirme *empire* et laisse l'*emprise* sans *colère*

> ***EMPIRE : C.*** − En partic. Ascendant, influence morale de quelqu'un, de quelque chose sur une personne, une de ses facultés. Sous l'empire de la colère, de la passion. J'ai perdu tout empire sur moi-même (Staël, Lettr. L. de Narbonne,1794, p. 246). Cet homme exerçait un empire absolu sur mon imagination (Chênedollé, Journal,1815, p. 74). Sous l'empire du haschisch, je ne peux pas me retenir de voler (Gide, Faux-monn.,1925, 1227).

Ce qui fait que la version soutenue et utilisée par la justice<sup>1</sup> est "*Sous l'empire de la colère*" : la Colère étant un empire imaginaire qui prend le contrôle des émotions humaines révoltées.

- ***L'empire de la colère*** : la colère a pris l'ascendant sur le mental de quelqu'un, sur ses facultés ; c'est l'expression académique qui défini un humain débordé et soumis à cette émotion.

Mais *emprise* est un paronyme<sup>2</sup> d'*empire*.

*[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=empire%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%2Cemprise%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cempire%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemprise%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0)* nous indique que depuis la fin de la seconde guerre mondiale, qu'être "*Sous l'emprise de la colère*" est devenu l'expression la plus souvent utilisée pour désigner le même état explosif d'un être humain.

Le *[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/emprise)* laisse l'*emprise* aux personnes ou aux objets qui peuvent laisser une trace, une *empreinte* dans la réalité :

> ***EMPRISE II.−*** P. ext. et p. croisement sém. avec *empire, empreinte*.
> A.− Ascendant intellectuel ou moral exercé par quelqu'un ou quelque chose sur un individu. Avoir de l'emprise sur qqn : nous suivent,1926, p. 171. [...]
> B.− Plus rare. Domination physique. [...]

*L'Emprise* est une domination intellectuelle ou morale, cela ne convient pas avec le mot colère qui vient de soi-même et non pas de l'extérieur : on ne peut être sous l'emprise que de quelqu'un, d'une institution, d'une secte...

- ***L'emprise de la colère*** est une expression usuelle, bien qu'elle soit comprise par tous au début de ce troisième millénaire, elle est erronée lorsqu'elle est utilisée avec le mot *colère, passion* ou tout autre sentiment.

*Un moyen mnémotechnique :* il faut suivre la justice et se dire qu'elle ne peut demander à la police de passer les bracelets à la *colère* pour en faire une accusée ou pour annexer son *empire* !
Alors qu'elle peut le faire pour envoyer en prison un prévenu s'il est démontré qu'il a une *emprise* coupable sur un tiers.

Avant la colère était perçue comme un 'démon' :

Autour de 1675, dans une France en prise avec l'Église, *[le démon de la colère](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=empire%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%2Cemprise%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%2C%20d%C3%A9mon%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cempire%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemprise%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9mon%20de%20la%20col%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0)* a fait florès, puis est retombé ; il reste une des expressions les moins utilisées pour signifier qu'un homme est passé sous "*la domination de la colère*", que "*son esprit est possédé par la colère*" .

- ***Le démon de la colère, être sous la domination de la colère, être possédé par la colère*** sont des expressions qui trouvent leur origine dans le domaine religieux, mais sont tout à fait utilisables pour essayer de traduire un état émotif particulier, celui de la perte de contrôle de soi, surtout lorsqu'il s'agit de porter un jugement moral.

P.S. : On peut aussi remplacer *colère* par *passion* lorsque cette dernière est destructrice.

---

1. [Archive de http://blog.profdedroit.com/post/2010/03/20/sous-l-empire-ou-sous-l-emprise](http://web.archive.org/web/20200222173346/http://blog.profdedroit.com/post/2010/03/20/sous-l-empire-ou-sous-l-emprise).
2. mots phonétiquement semblables mais de sens différents.

Comment: Dans la mesure où le PO nous cite un texte qui ressort du domaine légal, je te suggère de compléter ta réponse avec [cette référence](http://blog.profdedroit.com/post/2010/03/20/sous-l-empire-ou-sous-l-emprise) d'un blog de prof de droit.

Comment: @Laure -- Merci, excellent conseil !

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Bonne remarque, réponse corrigée :) .